# How to get a forked code files into my local computer from GitHub?

Tags: git, github

I am new to GitHub. I have forked a big sized codebase from an instructor who has posted it on GitHub. Now it is under my GitHub account. I want to get the code into my local computer so that I could work on it. I see an option, Clone\Download. I think if I use it, it will download a disconnected copy of the code files into my local computer which I don't want to do. I would like to make changes in my local computer and then push the changes to GitHub.

Comment: Check the [Github Help pages](https://help.github.com/en#dotcom) specifically: [Cloning a Repository](https://help.github.com/en/articles/cloning-a-repository) ("_You can clone your repository to create a local copy on your computer and sync between the two locations._").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Cloning* the repository to your local machine, via `git clone <GitHub link>` will maintain the upstream info, as per the official [docs](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-clone):

> Clones a repository into a newly created directory, **creates remote-tracking branches for each branch** in the cloned repository (visible using git branch --remotes), and creates and checks out an initial branch that is forked from the cloned repository’s currently active branch.

Once you are ready to update your repository on GitHub, you can `git push` to have your local and online copy synced.